# Ties to Home country USA (Domestic partnership, Civil Union)

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, nigerian-citizens, proof-of-ties

2 quick questions i wanted to ask on here , I was denied a US Visa this March, before i applied for another country (still waiting Visa decision) Now I have been looking out for possible reasons why the visa was refused, I have not come to a reasonable conclusion , so i wanted to ask on here what could be the possible reason.

Now, here is what. He (V.O) asked me if I was married and If I have traveled out of the country before , i replied both in the negative and he handed me a blue paper. I started to think my marital status was the worry, I have been engulfed with work, hence, I do not see leaving the country as a Must in this case.

Should I have to fill the DS-160 again (If i have to re-apply again at this point), could I enter that I am in a Civil Union / domestic partnership with someone (Of which I am presently, although it did escape my mind as I am apparently not married to her yet.) And secondly, does anyone think the travel issue is a barrier as well?

Comment: What did they say the reason for the refusal was? Or does the US not actually tell you why?

Comment: Both of the reasons you mentioned are an issue. For US non-immigrant visas, you have to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent. With no previous travel history, no marital ties and coming from a country with a high immigration risk profile, your chances of receiving a visa from the US or equivalent regime (Canada, UK, Schengen etc) are vanishingly small.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist he did not even look at the documents or even tell me anything. He just asked me what i wanted to do in the US, i told him i was going for a Conference, he then asked me those two questions , i did not have to lie, i told him the truth, yes i was not married and I have not been anywhere before, Man gave me a Blue paper.

Comment: @Traveller, wow, Are you saying being in a domestic partnership / civil union cannot work as well?

Comment: @The Miz No, sorry, I didn’t mean to imply that in my comment. A civil union or other legally recognised partnership in your home country would be relevant providing documentation is available to prove it. This https://de.usembassy.gov/interview-and-supporting-documents/ might help to explain better the interview process